# Django 1.10 404.html template not found

Tags: python, django

As far as I have seen in the Django documentation, to show a custom 404 page all you have to do is put a 404.html in the root templates directory.

So my project structure is:

```
django_project
|_ config
| |_ settings.py
| |_ urls.py
|
|_ templates
  |_ base.html
  |_ index.html
  |_ 404.html
```

In settings.py I have the following settings for the templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates", ]
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'contact.views.contact_info',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

for the `'DIRS'` parameter I also used `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")`. This had the exact same outcome.

I also used

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), 
)
```

This lead to a deprecation warning.

In urls.py I also did not really do anything special:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="index"),

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Template inheritance is working perfectly in other apps, so the templates directory is found.

In settings: `DEBUG=False`

When I enter a wrong url I get the Django default 'NOT FOUND' page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, one thing that is missing is any description of the actual problem. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need override 'handler404' variable, add this to urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404

handler404 = 'your_app.views.404'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to specify route for your 404.html template, or use from django shortcuts 'get_object_or_404' to handle error 404.